# QGIS: Cross-tabulation table full of zero values

Tags: qgis, raster, cross-tabulation

I want to calculate the *Night Light Development Index* (NLDI). For this reason I am using a night-time lights satellite image and a population raster layer, which they have the same dimensions, extent and projection system. In order to calculate the index, firstly, I need to create a table like the one in the image attached. I have found that I can use the function `Cross-Classification and Tabulation` in `QGIS`. The problem is that when I am using the function the resulting table is full of 0 values. Any idea what might be the issue?
Here are my data:

```
new("RasterStack", filename = "", layers = list(new("RasterLayer", 
    file = new(".RasterFile", name = "C:\\Users\\Geography\\Desktop\\esda\\mumbai\\2018\\pop.tif", 
        datanotation = "FLT4S", byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, 
        NAchanged = FALSE, nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, 
        toptobottom = TRUE, blockrows = 9L, blockcols = 215L, 
        driver = "gdal", open = FALSE), data = new(".SingleLayerData", 
        values = logical(0), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = FALSE, 
        fromdisk = TRUE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), 
        haveminmax = TRUE, min = 10.014267921448, max = 601.32739257812, 
        band = 1L, unit = "", names = "pop"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
        type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
        names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
    extent = new("Extent", xmin = 582800, xmax = 604300, ymin = 1005700, 
        ymax = 1047400), rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", 
        geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 215L, nrows = 417L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=lcc +lat_0=18.88015774 +lon_0=76.75 +lat_1=16.625 +lat_2=21.125 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
    history = list(), z = list()), new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", 
    name = "C:\\Users\\Geography\\Desktop\\esda\\mumbai\\2018\\nov\\ntl_atprk.tif", 
    datanotation = "FLT8S", byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, 
    NAchanged = FALSE, nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, 
    toptobottom = TRUE, blockrows = 4L, blockcols = 215L, driver = "gdal", 
    open = FALSE), data = new(".SingleLayerData", values = logical(0), 
    offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = FALSE, fromdisk = TRUE, 
    isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), haveminmax = TRUE, 
    min = 0.32394027709961, max = 348.45766448975, band = 1L, 
    unit = "", names = "ntl_atprk"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
    type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
    names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
    extent = new("Extent", xmin = 582800, xmax = 604300, ymin = 1005700, 
        ymax = 1047400), rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", 
        geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 215L, nrows = 417L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=lcc +lat_0=18.88015774 +lon_0=76.75 +lat_1=16.625 +lat_2=21.125 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
    history = list(), z = list())), title = character(0), extent = new("Extent", 
    xmin = 582800, xmax = 604300, ymin = 1005700, ymax = 1047400), 
    rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), 
        transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 215L, nrows = 417L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=lcc +lat_0=18.88015774 +lon_0=76.75 +lat_1=16.625 +lat_2=21.125 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
    history = list(), z = list())
```

[image]